# ValueError shape mismatch objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to plot a third stacked bar in matplotlib following this post on stackoverflow : [A third stacked bar in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43530494/a-third-stacked-bar-in-matplotlib)

But I have an Value error as mentionned in title and I don't understand why as I followed the exact same process as in the post...

Here is the code :

```
    count_faithfull = [2806862, 2798370, 2793310, 2786216, 2780627, 2773589, 2769471, 2764706, 2758180, 2753428, 2745208, 2745208]
    count_coward = [15088, 16216, 11432, 11658, 11862, 14706, 12864, 14006, 15327, 12614, 15002, 0]
    count_recruit = [0, 6372, 4564, 6273, 7668, 8746, 9241, 8801, 7862, 6782, 6463, 6463] 
    width = 0.35
    year = list(range(202001, 202013)) #We take the last year
    p1 = plt.bar(year, count_recruit, width, color='#d62728', )
    p2 = plt.bar(year, count_coward, width,  bottom=count_recruit)
    p3 = plt.bar(year, count_faithfull, width,  bottom=count_recruit+count_coward)
    
    plt.ylabel('Scores')
    plt.title('Scores by group and gender')
    plt.gca().ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 81, 10))
    plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0], p3[0]), ('Faithfull', 'Coward', "Recruit"))
    
    plt.show()
```

Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `count_recruit+count_coward` creates a large list instead of adding them up like in the example you linked. In the example they used `numpy` arrays which are added up by the `+` sign.

You could first add the lists up elementwise, and then use them:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
count_faithfull = [2806862, 2798370, 2793310, 2786216, 2780627, 2773589, 2769471, 2764706, 2758180, 2753428, 2745208,
                   2745208]
count_coward = [15088, 16216, 11432, 11658, 11862, 14706, 12864, 14006, 15327, 12614, 15002, 0]
count_recruit = [0, 6372, 4564, 6273, 7668, 8746, 9241, 8801, 7862, 6782, 6463, 6463]
width = 0.35
year = list(range(202001, 202013))  # We take the last year
p1 = plt.bar(year, count_recruit, width, color='#d62728', )
p2 = plt.bar(year, count_coward, width, bottom=count_recruit)
L=[i+j for i,j in zip(count_coward,count_recruit)]
p3 = plt.bar(year,count_recruit, width, bottom=L)

plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores by group and gender')
plt.gca().ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 81, 10))
plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0], p3[0]), ('Faithfull', 'Coward', "Recruit"))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the following: `count_coward` and `count_recruit` are `lists`, so when you use `+` it is not doing elementwise `sum`, instead, it is just creating a bigger list with all the elements which are in both lists:

```
print(count_recruit + count_coward)

>>> [0, 6372, 4564, 6273, 7668, 8746, 9241, 8801, 7862, 6782, 6463, 6463, 15088, 16216, 11432, 11658, 11862, 14706, 12864, 14006, 15327, 12614, 15002, 0]
```

Because of that, you have a size mismatch, since `year` and `count_faithfull` have lengths equal to 12.
So you need to do an elementwise sum of 2 equal length lists:

Option 1: use numpy

```
import numpy as np


p3 = plt.bar(
    year, count_faithfull, width,  
    bottom=np.array(count_recruit)+np.array(count_coward)
)
```

Option 2: use list comprehension

```
p3 = plt.bar(
    year, count_faithfull, width,  
    bottom=[x + y for x, y in zip(count_recruit, count_coward)]
)
```